# Dealing with files in app running inside AppImage

Tags: c++, qt, appimage

I have an application written in Qt/C++ which is running under Linux.
Inside my application I have several functions which dealing with files located in:

- `QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()`
- `/tmp/`
- `QStandardPaths::ConfigLocation`
- `QStandardPaths::DataLocation`

The application runs smoothly if executes as regular Linux executable. However there are problems if I pack it into AppImage. It doesn't see files in expected locations and can't create new files in there.
If I understand AppImage correctly - it is SquashFS which is readonly. So this behavior is understandable. But how can I deal with? Is that possible to solve this problem without changing source code of my app?

The output of `QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath()` when run the Linux executable is `"/home/mike/projects/builds/build-testqtapp-Desktop_Qt_5_12_8_GCC_64bit-Debug/AppDir/testqtapp"` The output of the same command from AppImage is `"/tmp/.mount_testqtyEZUuH/testqtapp"`

Comment: why do you care about the path to the executable? Thats not where you should be putting data files. Show the actual code you are having a problem with.

Comment: The executable is looking for some files just near itself. I can revise it in the code, but I don't want to change it..